# Connect picker wheel delegate

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uipickerview

How do you connect the "delegate" of the Picker Wheel to the interface? This seemed so simple in the tutorial, but in Xcode there is no "pickerview delegate" button I can use to drag to interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

You need to connect the delegate to the `pickerView`, even though there is no spesific button for it. Just right-click the orange square box beside your interface builder, and press down `CTRL` while you drag 'New referencing outlet' to the picker. When you drop the line on the picker, there will be an option to add pickerView delegate and datasource! :)

You will need to implement the delegates in your header file aswell, like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController     <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem, thanks to other people as well:)

Answer (score 0):

Add your ViewController as a UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Those options should be there now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your storyboard/xib file.
2. Open the Inspector window (Right most button in the view sections here
   [image]
3. Open the connections inspector (Right most button in this area at the top of the inspector window)
   [image]
4. Drag from the circle next to the "delegate" entry to what you want to be the delegate
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Select picker, right click on it. Then you see a menu — list with circles on the left side.
Click and drag from circle opposite to delegate to the controller yellow icon.